# Why this form encodes apostrophes using HTML entities and leaves latin accented letters the way they are?

Tags: html, spring, encoding

I am trying to solve a bug for an application here at the company I work for. I have a weird problem: basically if I type the following string in a textarea `Hello 'd'd' nénéné` it will RECEIVE (server side) it posted to my app Controller (Spring) in the following way: `Hello &#39;d&#39;d&#39; nénéné`.... the weird thing is that the accented Es remain unchanged, while the apostrophe gets escaped... but then on the controller side there is no escaping.

I am using spring, but I really don't know if there are Filter or Interceptors doing some weird stuff in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's a Spring [SQL injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) protection: `'` must whatever be escaped when sent to a server, whereas `é` isn't dangerous.

Comment: It was indeed! poor me I wasted so much time